# How can we change the title "Sign in with Apple" to just "Apple" in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sign-in-with-apple

I want to sign in with Apple in my objective C project, but the requirement is to change the title to "Apple" instead of "Sign in with Apple".
Is there any way to change the title of "ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton" ?

Comment: No, but you can [create a custom button](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/buttons/#creating-a-custom-sign-in-with-apple-button)

Comment: have you done it in your project? can you share your code to create custom button? @Alladinian

Comment: Sorry never done it but isn't it straight forward? They even provide assets (like logos) and guidance for font sizes and layout.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple/overview/introduction/

Comment: This is so ridiculous! Can't they just add a label text property to their existing sign in button?!